# Show in draft mode, hide in final mode

Tags: packages

I am writing a paper which has some parts which I want to hide in the final pdf output but displayed in draft pdf output (that is when I am working on the paper). So I need an environment which is displayed in the draft mode, but hidden in the final mode and I want to do this by simply changing a setting in the preamble. Is this possible?

Comment: Packages like `comment` and [some more](http://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp) can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newif\ifdone %\donetrue % uncomment when done
\begin{document}
Always visible.  \ifdone Final only \fi.

\ifdone Theorem \else Conjecture \fi: This paper will one day be finished.
\end{document}
```